# String compression function in python code

Tags: python, strings

I need to create a function called compress that compresses a string by replacing any repeated letters with a letter and number. Can someone suggest a better way to do this?

```
s=input("Enter the string:")
temp={}
result=" "
for x in s:
    if x in temp:
        temp[x]=temp[x]+1
    else:
        temp[x]=1
for key,value in temp.items():
    result+=str(key)+str(value)
        print(result)
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to actually solve the problem you stated. The order of letters is not preserved and if a letter only occures once you add a `1` instead of just outputting it (`"aba" -> "a2b1"` instead of `"aba" -> "aba"`).

Comment: In addition to the problem Graipher reported, there is also unexepected indentation on the last line...

Answer (score 11):

## Encapsulate your code into functions

Your code is neither reusable nor testable, wrap it into a function and call it from under an [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5069029) guard. This will allow you to test it more easily. You will also be able to return values instead of printing them, this will make the code more reusable:

```
def compress(string):
    temp={}
    result=" "
    for x in string:
        if x in temp:
            temp[x] = temp[x]+1
        else:
            temp[x] = 1
    for key, value in temp.items():
        result += str(key) + str(value)

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input("Enter the string:")
    print(compress(s))
```

You can then jump into an interactive shell and type:

```
>>> from your_file_name import compress
>>> compress('aaabbccccddefg')
 a3b2c4d2e1f1g1
>>> compress('b'*42)
 b42
```

## Use existing data structures

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) offers simplified ways of counting elements of an iterable:

```
from collections import Counter


def compress(string):
    temp = Counter()
    result = " "
    for x in string:
        temp[x] += 1

    for key, value in temp.items():
        result += str(key) + str(value)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input("Enter the string:")
    print(compress(s))
```

You can even simplify further as `Counter` can take any iterable in its constructor. You can also use `str.join` to simplify even further:

```
from collections import Counter


def compress(string):
    counts = Counter(string)
    return ''.join(letter+str(count) for letter, count in counts.items())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(compress(input("Enter the string: ")))
```

## Possible bug

To me, compressing a string mean having a mean to decompress it back. Using a dictionnary keyed by each letter as you do, you lost an important information: which letter is next to which one. Also `'aabaabaabaa'` will be compressed to `'a8b3'` which, to me, doesn't make sense and would be better as `'a2b1a2b1a2b1a2'`. But I might be wrong. In this case, [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is much more usefull as it will keep the ordering and avoid aggregating separate groups of letters:

```
import itertools


def compress(string):
    return ''.join(
            letter + str(len(list(group)))
            for letter, group in itertools.groupby(string))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(compress(input("Enter the string: ")))
```

Comment: And then encoding `'f'` as `'f1'` is the opposite of compressing. But if you find a nice way to write it as a comprehension that would be nice, I could not think of any.

Comment: @Graipher For `'f'` -> `'f1'` I chose to keep the original behaviour

Comment: @Graipher But something like `letter + str(length := len(list(group))) if length > 1 else ''` could work in upcomming Python 3.8

Comment: The more I look at it, the code of the OP does not solve the stated problem at all...

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along those lines as well. But I only have 3.6 installed :)

Answer (score 2):

In the `itertools` module there is the [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function that groups together runs of the same values.

You can use it like this here:

```
from itertools import groupby

def compress(s):
    out = []
    for name, group in groupby(s):
        length_of_run = len(list(group))
        if length_of_run == 1:
            out.append(name)
        else:
            out.append(f"{name}{length_of_run}")
    return "".join(out)
```

This also uses the more modern [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) instead of manually building the string with `str` calls and `+` and puts everything into a function that you can reuse.

It also has the advantage that it directly iterates over the input, instead of over its indices (have a look at [Loop like a Native!](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html)). This makes it work also for a generator, which does not have a length:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle

compress(islice(cycle('a'), 10))
# 'a10'
```

Answer (score -2):

This could be one of the way to do it:

```
count = 1
for i in range(1, len(input) + 1):
    if i == len(input):
        print(input[i - 1] + str(count), end="")
        break
    else:
        if input[i - 1] == input[i]:
            count += 1
    else:
            print(input[i - 1] + str(count), end="")
            count = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, something wrong with my code?

Comment: Not really, just suggested you a better way to perform the same per your question.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.